# subscript for coupling constant J

Tags: subscripts, chemmacros

I'm using `chemmacros` package to typeset NMR experimental data with coupling constant J with subscripts to designate the two atoms involved. It works fine but when I want to specify which atoms are involved in the coupling (mainly two hydrogens with their position, e.g. H5,H6) I can't do it with a subscript, since the atoms appear in parenthesis and the position as a subscript (like it was a molecular formula).

This is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[spanish.tabla.notilde]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemnum,chemstyle}

\usepackage{chemmacros}[2014/01/29] 
\chemsetup[nmr]{
  delta = (ppm) ,
  pos-number = side ,
  use-equal,
  format = \bfseries,
  list=true ,
}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  separate-uncertainty ,
  per-mode = symbol ,
  range-phrase = -- ,
  detect-mode = false ,
  detect-weight = true ,
  mode = text ,
}

\begin{document}

This is what I have:
\begin{experimental}
\NMR(300)[CDCl3] 6.26 (d, \J[Hz]{7.26}), 5.77 (\#{1}, dt, \J(;H4H5)[Hz]{15.3}, \J(;H5H6)[Hz]{6.6}), 2.23 (\#{2}, t, \J[Hz]{7.6}, \pos{2'}), 2.04 (\#{2}, m, \pos{6})
\end{experimental}

This is what I want:
\begin{experimental}
\NMR(300)[CDCl3] 6.26 (d, \J[Hz]{7.26}), 5.77 (\#{1}, dt, $J_{H4H5}=$  \SI{15.3}{\Hz}, $J_{H5H6}=$  \SI{6.6}{\Hz}), 2.23 (\#{2}, t, \J[Hz]{7.6}, \pos{2'}), 2.04 (\#{2}, m, \pos{6})
\end{experimental}
but subscripts H4H5 neither H5H6 shouldn't be in italics

 \end{document}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps `$J_{\mathrm{H4,H5}}=\SI{15.3}{\Hz}$`?

Comment: Yes, with `$J_{\mathrm{H4,H5}}=\SI{15.3}{\Hz}$` I get desired result, but I thought there were some way to do it with `\J(;⟨nuclei⟩)`

Comment: That's why I just wrote a comment.

Comment: Add the key `coupling-pos=sub` at `\chemsetup` list.

Comment: Good! with `coupling-pos=sub` it works! thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I say in my comment, you can use the `coupling-pos` key, which controls the position of coupling nuclei. You can set `side` (default value) or `sub`. The second value is what you you need.

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{chemmacros}[2014/01/29] 
\chemsetup[nmr]{
  delta = (ppm) ,
  pos-number = side ,
  use-equal,
  format = \bfseries,
  list=true ,
}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{
  separate-uncertainty ,
  per-mode = symbol ,
  range-phrase = -- ,
  detect-mode = false ,
  detect-weight = true ,
  mode = text ,
}

\begin{document}
% coupling-pos = side, default value
\begin{experimental}
\NMR(300)[CDCl3] 6.26 (d, \J[Hz]{7.26}), 5.77 (\#{1}, dt, \J(;H4H5)[Hz]{15.3}, \J(;H5H6)[Hz]{6.6}), 2.23 (\#{2}, t, \J[Hz]{7.6}, \pos{2'}), 2.04 (\#{2}, m, \pos{6})
\end{experimental}

% coumpling-pos = sub
\chemsetup[nmr]{ coupling-pos = sub }
\begin{experimental}
\NMR(300)[CDCl3] 6.26 (d, \J[Hz]{7.26}), 5.77 (\#{1}, dt, \J(;H4H5)[Hz]{15.3}, \J(;H5H6)[Hz]{6.6}), 2.23 (\#{2}, t, \J[Hz]{7.6}, \pos{2'}), 2.04 (\#{2}, m, \pos{6})
\end{experimental}

 \end{document}
```